# create a reverse method where elements are reversed in array

Tags: java

Here list is the name of the array. I have a swap method so trying to use it to make a reverse method of an array string. so if the elements in an array are 1,2,3,4 they should become 4,3,2,1. I don;t understand where the flaw is in my logic as with my current code only the first and last elements are getting swapped.

```
 private void swap(int i, int j)

    {
        int temp;

        temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = temp;

    } 

    public void reverse()
    {
        int y=1; 
        for(int x =0; x<list.length-1; x++)
        {
        swap(x,list.length-y);
        ++y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? You swap each pair of elements twice.

Comment: Use `x < list.length / 2` as the upper bound in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
int y=1;
        // add and/or modify code to complete the method 
        for(int x =0; x<list.length-1; x++)  //wrong, should only loop to len/2
        {
        swap(x,list.length-y);
        ++y;
        }
```

the right code should be:

```java
int mid = (list.length - 1) / 2;
int len = list.length;
for (int i = 0; i <= mid; i++) {
  swap(i, len - 1 - i);
}
```

Comment: this solved it, I'll accept when 5 minute is over. Can you explain why (list.length -1) /2 was done?

Comment: Ok, the solution is 0 swap len -1, 1 and len -2, and etc. So you only need to loop to (len -1 ) /2 then all the items in the array will be swaped